# Show that $Z_n = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i - n\mu }{\sigma \sqrt{n}}$ is equal to $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{X_i - \mu} { \sigma \sqrt{n}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Show that $Z_n = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i - n\mu }{\sigma \sqrt{n}}$ is equal to $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{X_i - \mu} { \sigma \sqrt{n}}$. I tried solving it, but I got the $\sqrt{n}$ to be in the numerator instead of the denominator. Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The denominator does not depend on $i$ and therefore it goes out in front of the summation. Using that
$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)-n\mu=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)-\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\mu\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu).
$$
we obtain
$$
\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i\right)-n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu)}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}
$$
which equals your expression.

Comment: That is what I did too, and I did the same for the summation in the denominator. However, this does not give you the desired result, does it?

Comment: @cruise: Do you see it now?

Comment: The summation in the desired result also includes the $\sigma\sqrt{n}$ from the denominator if I am right. So then you would still have to divide $\sigma\sqrt{n}$ by $n$ in order for it to be in the summation, right?

Comment: @cruise: No, because $\sigma\sqrt{n}$ does not depend on $i$ and hence $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{X_i-\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu)}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}.$$ In general, $\sum_i a_i\cdot b=b\cdot \sum_i a_i$ if $b$ does not depend on $i$.

Comment: Ah ok, that I did not realize. Thanks for your help @StefanHansen

Comment: @cruise: You're welcome.